# IIS Management Console doesn't see the share on other domain: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: domains, shared-hosting, iis

Web server (W2008) is in domain1, I configured a web site to use a network share in domain2 with a username/password of domain2. I don't have admin rights on the NAS server but only on my share. there is a trust relation from domain1 to domain2. So in domain1 I could use domain2 user/password, but not vice versa: I don't see domain1 users from domain2.

Web site works well, test connection passes green, no problem. But when I login to web server with my domain2 user name ( I am in Administrators group) and start IIS Management console, I can't see folders under the web site icon. I click on + sign and I get error message "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." If I try to configure web site like add a rule I get another error:
Filename \?\UNC\nasserver.domain1...\web.config Error: Cannot write configuration file.

In the web server if I start windows explorer I can see folders!!

To test I mapped the share in web server; I can see files even though Windows explorer shows its letter as "Disconnected Network Drive". But I can't use it in IIS Manager, it says path doesn't exist. I searched on internet but most of the information is obsolete and is not relevant to W2008 and later.
( I don't know if it is relevant but the same share is managed without any problem from a W2008 web server server on domain2 )